# transparent css border as a place-holder

Tags: jquery, css

Please take a look at the following two fiddle files to see the problem I am struggling with:

I want a border on the hover effect for highlighting, but I am not satisfied with the two following codes I have:

http://jsfiddle.net/hnxan9ck/7/

This one is not satisfactory because the table wobbles as you mouse-over the rows, then I tried the following

http://jsfiddle.net/gyb314/hnxan9ck/4/

this does not work either, because the border is overlapped by the other borders of unselected rows.

```
.ui-datepicker-inline.ui-datepicker.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-helper-clearfix.ui-corner-all table.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody tr {
    border-style: none;
    border-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
    border-width: 4px;
}
.ui-datepicker-inline.ui-datepicker.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-helper-clearfix.ui-corner-all table.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody tr:hover {

    border-style: dotted;
    border-color:red;
    border-width: 4px;
}
```

So for the rows that is not hovered by the mouse, if I set the border to be none, then it wobbles, but if I set the border to be solid but transparent, it still blocks the border of hovered rows.

Is there a way to have a truly invisible place-holder border?

Comment: I don't see exactly what you're talking about, but I suspect your issues will go away if you set your box-model to be a border box and not a padding box.

Comment: have you tried adding margins to the row the same size as the border and then remove the margin adn add a border?  im not sure how that would go but it seems reasonable.

Comment: @Burrito: You can not add a margin for a table row, it simply doesn’t apply to table-row elements. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#margin-properties

Comment: aaah thank you, im more of a backend type guy but figured I would throw out a suggestion, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/hnxan9ck/8/

Just use `outline` instead of `border` to add the border color and it should work beautifully :)

```
.ui-datepicker-inline.ui-datepicker.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-helper-clearfix.ui-corner-all table.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody tr {
    outline: 2px dotted white;
}
.ui-datepicker-inline.ui-datepicker.ui-widget.ui-widget-content.ui-helper-clearfix.ui-corner-all table.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody tr:hover {
    outline: 2px dotted red;
}
```